# How to extract br text from span element?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

Using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) v4, I've a `span` as follows:

```
<span style="color: grey;">32.44 MB<br/>10454 Downloads<br/>35:25 Mins<br/>128kbps Stereo</span>
```

I'd like to extract the text for the `br` elements individually. How can I do it?

Comment: Is this html correct? Where are the opening `br` tags?

Comment: @Sushil This is what's there; everyone is a web dev these days, so...

Comment: Hahaha...I can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<span style="color: grey;">32.44 MB<br/>10454 Downloads<br/>35:25 Mins<br/>128kbps Stereo</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('span br'):
    print(tag.next)
```

Output:

```
10454 Downloads
35:25 Mins
128kbps Stereo
```

Answer (score 0):

although this may not be proper way to do that, but if you use your span as a string, you can extract the words like this:

```
user_input = '<span style="color: grey;">32.44 MB<br/>10454 Downloads<br/>35:25 Mins<br/>128kbps Stereo</span>'.split( "<br/>" )
WordList = []
for word in user_input:
    if ">" in word:
        word = word[word.index(">")+1:]
    if word:
        WordList.append( [word] )
print(WordList)
```